# How to make T-SQL Select Between Several Options

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I'm still pretty new to SQL. I'm writing (actually upgrading) a stored procedure that addresses mailings.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    Greeting_ID,
    Client_ID,
    Envelope_Greeting,
    Letter_Greeting     
FROM 
    t_Cust_Greetings  
WHERE
    customer_no = 1234
```

Produces output something like this:

```
Greeting_ID Client_ID   Envelope_Greeting   Letter_Greeting
----------------------------------------------------------------
1            1234   Mr. and Mrs. John Smith  Mr. and Mrs. Smith
3            1234   Mr. and Mrs. John Smith  John and Jolene
6            1234   Mr. John Smith           Mr. Smith
7            1234   Mr. and Mrs. John Smith  Jolene and John
8            1234   Mrs. Jolene Smith        Jolene
12           1234   Mrs. Jolene Smith        Mrs. Jolene
```

Not every client has every type of greeting, and #1 is the default. The upgraded procedure needs to select #7 if it exists, but if not select #3, but if not #3 then go to default. I've had no success doing this with coalesce or a case statement.

How do you do something like this in T-SQL?

Comment: Can you add the coalesce and case statements that you've tried, and explain why they didn't work?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY CASE Greeting_ID WHEN 7 THEN 1 WHEN 3 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END, Greeting_ID`? It depends on whether #7 is always the greeting you want to select first if it exists against any client ID.

Comment: **The real solution is to save the data properly.**  Combining multiple names in one text field seems like a simple approach, but that has doomed you.  You will forever mess with string manipulation to try and get what you want.  Most likely you will never get one query that works all the time.  If you redesign the database to properly store each name part: Prefix (Mrs./Mr./Dr.), FirstName, LastName, etc in their own column, and separate different names into different rows, you could easily concatenate these together.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, but case should have worked. I don't have SQL installed to test it.

```
SELECT TOP(1) 
    Greeting_ID,
    Client_ID,
    Envelope_Greeting,
    Letter_Greeting     
FROM 
    t_Cust_Greetings  
WHERE
    Greeting_ID in (7,3,1)
    AND customer_no=1234
ORDER BY
    Greeting_ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

your condition line *select #7 if it exists, but if not select #3, but if not #3 then go to default.* can be translated as *select either of 7,3, or 1*. You can probably include a `IN` operator for that in your `WHERE`condition like

```
WHERE Greeting_ID IN (7, 3, 1)
```

Since you are performing this inside a procedure block; you can as well use `IF .. ELSE` construct.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should store the order you want in a separate table then order by that.  But using what you have you could try...

```
SELECT top 1
    Greeting_ID,
    Client_ID,
    Envelope_Greeting,
    Letter_Greeting     
FROM 
    t_Cust_Greetings  
WHERE
    customer_no = 1234
ORDER BY CASE Greeting_ID 
  WHEN 7 THEN 1 
  WHEN 3 THEN 2 
  WHEN 1 THEN 3 
  ELSE 4 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a table with values and their weight/order of preference.
- Join to that table with a select top 1 with an order by to get preferred value

Your SQL platform may not allow a from-less table as below - substitute your own temp table or table variable, or a case statement.

```
select top 1 * 
from t_Cust_Greetings hiYa
join ( values 
        (7,1) 
      , (3,2) 
      , (1,3) 
      ) Prefs (value,weight) 
  on hiYa.Greeting_ID = Prefs.value 
where customer_no = 823165
order by Prefs.weight
```